# pyvista._vtk error. Bug located in mapdl.aplot()

Tags: python, vtk, pyvista, ansys, ansys-apdl

**Description of the bug**
I have a problem when I ran mapdl.aplot(show_area_numbering=True, color_areas=True)

This is output of my problem
There are something issue in pyvista._vtk when it try to import VTK9

Which Operating System are you using?
Windows

Which Python version are you using?
3.11

```
Show the Report!
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[9], line 1
----> 1 mapdl.aplot(show_area_numbering=True, color_areas=True)
---
File ~\anaconda3\envs\Pymapdl_20230804\lib\site-packages\ansys\mapdl\core\mesh\mesh.py:7
      5 import numpy as np
      6 import pyvista as pv
----> 7 from pyvista._vtk import VTK9
      9 INVALID_ALLOWABLE_TYPES = TypeError(
     10     "`allowable_types` must be an array " "of ANSYS element types from 1 and 300"
     11 )
     13 # map MESH200 elements to a pymapdl_reader/VTK element type (see elements.py)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyvista._vtk'`

-------------------------------------
Show the installed packages!
numpy==1.24.3
matplotlib==3.7.1
ipykernel==6.23.0
pandas == 2.0.1
tabulate == 0.9.0
openpyxl == 3.1.2
imageio == 2.28.1
ansys-mapdl-core==0.64.1
pyvista==0.40.4

I try many package, I also updated all newversion of libraries.
```

Comment: You also asked this [on the `pymapdl` issue tracker](https://github.com/ansys/pymapdl/issues/2227), which was the right call. You're much better off looking for an answer there. The error you get is legitimate on modern `pyvista`, so whatever library you're using (probably `ansys-mapdl-core` is not new enough). In any case the mapdl issue tracker will help you sort this out.